# Google chart's arrayToDataTable producing "Data for arrayToDataTable is not an array" in typescript (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, google-visualization

I am facing an issue with the google charts in angular.

While I am trying to create a data for the word tree using google.visualization.arrayToDataTable() method I am getting

> Data for arrayToDataTable is not an array

the corresponding snippet:

```
export class WordTreeComponent implements OnInit {


dummy1 : any[] = ["id", "childLabel", "parent", "size", { role: "style" }],
 [0, "Life", -1, 1, "black"],;
 
  ngOnInit(){

   google.charts.load("current", {
     "packages": ["WordTree"]
   });

   this.nodeListData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.dummy1 as any[], false) ;
  }
}
```

the error screen shot:

[image]

I guessing whether it is related with typescripts array data type handling (typeof array is object) but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayToDataTable` expects an array of arrays.

here, you have two single arrays.

```
dummy1 : any[] = ["id", "childLabel", "parent", "size", { role: "style" }], [0, "Life", -1, 1, "black"],;
```

which need to be included in an overall array.

```
dummy1 : any[] = [["id", "childLabel", "parent", "size", { role: "style" }], [0, "Life", -1, 1, "black"]];
```

---

also, you should be waiting for google charts to fully load,
before trying to use the `google.visualization` namespace.

use the promise that the load statement returns...

```
google.charts.load("current", {
  "packages": ["WordTree"]
}).then(function () {
  this.nodeListData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.dummy1 as any[], false) ;
});
```

Comment: I tried that which cause "Unknown type of value, [object Object]".